# Laravel eloquent relationship between tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Got stuck in Laravel eloquent relationships. I have two tables.

**fuel** contains

- id,  fuel_name,  fuel_rate

**machine** contains

- id,  machine_name, machine_rate   fuel_id

  fields.

fuel_id is a foreign key.

I have tried  some examples from laravel.com

in ***Machine.php***

```
class Machine extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'machine';

    public  function machineinfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Fuel','id');
    }
}
```

and in controller

```
$items = Machine::find(1)->machineinfo;
```

I want to see
machine name, machine code, fuel name and fuel rate in output.

But the output is

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fuel.machine_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `fuel` where `fuel`.`machine_id` = 1 and `fuel`.`machine_id` is not null)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ending of the section **laravel hasMany** here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

The second parameter to hasMany is a foreign key, that means in this case **fuel_id** in the **machine** table. So rather than passing **'id'** as a second parameter, you should send **'fuel_id'** in

`$this->hasMany('App\Fuel','fuel_id')`.

Also, you may not need to use the second parameter. See the naming convention in the same link above. The foreign key is automatically detected based on theprovided `App\Fuel` class.